# how to extract strings in excel in a specified format using string formula?

Tags: excel

```
Tendulkar,Sachin Ramesh  
"=CONCATENATE(MID(C7,FIND(",",C7)+1,8)," ",LEFT(C7,FIND(",",C7)-1))"
```

For the above string, I want it as "Sachin R Tendulkar". I had written the above formula and it is working fine. Is there any other way to make dynamically Like instead of counting the characters and specifying it in find function?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it works, why change it? I assume that the names will have varying numbers of characters, so in order to find the comma and the space your best bet is with the current approach. Why fix it if it isn't broken?

Comment: yeah cool but what can we do if the length of the name is so longer?It consumes more time to count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to find "Sachin", you can use: `=mid(F17,find(",", F17,1)+1,len(F17)-find(" ",F17))` this finds the next number of letters after the comma until the space.
To find R, you can use: `=mid(F17,find(" ",F17)+1,1)` this finds the first letter of the name after the space. Finally, you use `=left(F17,find(",",F17)-1)` to find the first name up until the comma.
Then we can concatenate these three strings with spaces as follows:

```
=CONCATENATE(mid(F17,find(",", F17,1)+1,len(F17)-find(" ",F17))," ",MID(F17,find(" ",F17)+1,1)," ",left(F17,find(",",F17)-1))
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: But, Instead to extract "Sachin", you had calculated to extract "Ramesh"  @Daniel

Comment: I disagree, try paste this exactly :`=CONCATENATE(mid(C7,find(",", C7,1)+1,len(C7)-find(" ",C7))," ",MID(C7,find(" ",C7)+1,1)," ",left(C7,find(",",C7)-1))`

Comment: Sorry for the chaos, it is giving me the right answer but when i thought logically, it was like to extract "Ramesh".  It helps me a lot:)